# What am i doing wrong with my php regex

Tags: php, regex

I put together a regex to replace anything that is not:

1. a letter of the american alphabet regardless of capitalization
2. a number
3. a period
4. a whitespace
5. a comma
6. a question Mark
7. an exclamation mark
8. a dollar sign

regex: `/[^0-9a-zA-Z\$\s\.\,\?\!\$]+/m`

I put together the regex so it could replace all unwanted characters and compare the resulting string to its orignal string. The regex only works when the input method is a text input, when it is a textarea, it replaces all returns and tabs and spaces. what am i doing wrong?

```
<form method="get" action="" style="border-bottom:solid 1px lightGrey;">
string:<br>
<textarea name="a"><?php $av=(isset($_GET))?$_GET['a']:""; echo $av; ?></textarea><br><br>
regex:<br>
<input type="text" name="b" value="<?php $bv=(isset($_GET))?$_GET['b']:""; echo $bv; ?>" /><br><br>
<input type='submit' value='done'/>
</form>
<?
if(isset($_GET)){
$count = null;
$returnValue = preg_replace($_GET["b"], '*', $_GET["a"], -1, $count);
echo "original string:<br>".$_GET['a']."<br><br>replacement string:<br>".$returnValue."<br><br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my tests, the [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php) was messing up with the inputs. I could solve it fixing inputs at the start of the script with:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['a'])){
    $_GET['a'] = stripslashes($_GET['a']);
    $_GET['b'] = stripslashes($_GET['b']);
}
?>
```

Working code at [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['a'])){
    $_GET['a'] = stripslashes($_GET['a']);
    $_GET['b'] = stripslashes($_GET['b']);
}
?>

<form method="get" action="" style="border-bottom:solid 1px lightGrey;">
string:<br>
<textarea name="a"><?php $av=(isset($_GET["b"]))?$_GET['a']:""; echo $av; ?></textarea><br><br>
regex:<br>
<input type="text" name="b" value="<?php $bv=(isset($_GET["b"]))?$_GET['b']:"/[^0-9a-zA-Z\\$\\s\\.\\,\\?\\!\\$]+/m"; echo $bv; ?>" /><br><br>
<input type='submit' value='done'/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_GET["b"])){
$count = null;
$returnValue = preg_replace($_GET["b"], '*', $_GET["a"], -1, $count);
    echo "original string:<br><pre>".$_GET['a']."</pre><br><br>replacement string:<br><pre>".$returnValue."</pre><br><br>";
}
?>
```